# How to create the MVC equivalent of WIF PassiveSignInStatus Control?

Tags: model-view-controller, wif

I have included the below in my MVC View page

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Base.Master"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

 <%@ Register TagPrefix = "idfx" Assembly = "Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace =  "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">

   <idfx:FederatedPassiveSignInStatus 
            ID="FederatedPassiveSignInStatus1" 
            runat="server" 
            OnSignedOut="FederatedPassiveSignInStatus1SignedOut" 
            SignOutText="Logout" 
            FederatedPassiveSignOut="true"   
            SignOutAction="FederatedPassiveSignOut" />
  </asp:Content>
```

Since this is MVC, I cannot have runat=”server” attribute. When I remove the runat attribute, the page loads ok, but the control is not get displayed. How can I achieve this in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Identity Training Kit or the samples in http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/62929 should show you ways of hooking WIF with MVC.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot use event driven server-side controls in ASP.NET MVC like you can in ASP.NET webforms. If you are using webforms, than using the **FederatedPassiveSignInStatus** control to do sign-out is absolutely the easiest method.

In MVC we are going to have to issue the wa=wsignout1.0 command to the STS provider manually. If you look at the

Take a look at the 'FederationWithMultiplePartnersAndAcs' project in the Microsoft patterns & practices Cliams Identity Guide projects located on CodePlex [here](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/62929). If you look at the `Logout()` method on the `HomeController`, you will see the following code which does what we need:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut(false);

        string issuer = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer;
        var signOut = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(issuer));
        return this.Redirect(signOut.WriteQueryString());
    }

    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is how you would need to implement the sign-out logic in MVC.